# Как из листа стрингов сделать лист объектов через обработку Stream?

Tags: java, строки, java-stream

Нужно из существующего листа стрингов сделать лист объектов Region, где id=порядковый номер, а name=буквенное значение. На выходе при таком коде region.size() = 0. Помогите найти ошибку.

```java
class Region {
    Long id;
    String name;

    public Region(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> bufreg = new ArrayList<>();
        bufreg.add("1. EU/");
        bufreg.add("2. RU/");
        bufreg.add("3. ASIA/");

        List<Region> regions = bufreg.stream()
                .map(i -> i.split("."))
                .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
                .map(a -> new Region(Long.valueOf(a[0]), a[1].trim()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(regions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `split()` принимает регулярное выражение, `.` - *метасимвол для поиска "любого символа"*. Если точка - разделитель, вам необходимо **экранировать** символ:

```
.map(i -> i.split("\\."))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) для получения индекса первого вхождения символа и метод [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) для получения подстроки до этого символа:

```java
class Region {
    Long id;
    String name;

    public Region(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + id + ", " + name + '}';
    }
}
```

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> bufreg = new ArrayList<>();
        bufreg.add("1. EU/");
        bufreg.add("2. RU/");
        bufreg.add("3. ASIA/");

        List<Region> regions =
            bufreg.stream()
                .map(e -> new Region(
                    Long.parseLong(e.substring(0, e.indexOf('.'))),
                    e.substring(e.indexOf('.') + 1, e.indexOf('/')).trim()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(regions); // [{1, EU}, {2, RU}, {3, ASIA}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```java
package com.somepackage;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    static class Region {
        Long id;
        String name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var bufreg = List.of("1. EU/", "2. RU/", "3. ASIA/");
        final var pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.\\s+([^/]+)/");

        List<Region> regions = bufreg.stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    final var matcher = pattern.matcher(e);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        final var id = matcher.group(1);
                        final var name = matcher.group(2);
                        return new Region(Long.parseLong(id), name);
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(regions);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
[Main.Region(id=1, name=EU), Main.Region(id=2, name=RU), Main.Region(id=3, name=ASIA)]
```